# How would you resolve "error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"?

Tags: android, android-fragments, overriding

This is the part that's causing the error

the code is within a **ListFragment**

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.listener = (SampleListListener)activity;
```

According to developer.android.com:
*"onAttach(Activity activity)
This method was deprecated in API level 24.1.0. See onAttach(Context)."*
should I find another way to implement this instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter should be `Context` instead `Activity`

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
```

Comment: do you know how to get the context of appcompatactivity?

Comment: @LarkFaust Every `Activity` Extends `Context` class. So, you can simply typecast your variable to `Context` class. Like `Context contx = (Context)activityVarialbeName;`